# JAVA: Confusion with instance reference

Tags: java, list, interface

I am having some pretty serious confusion about instance and their implementations.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileAddress),
    Charset.defaultCharset());
```

The above code is valid because I know that `List<String>` is an interface but I can use it's type as a reference variable and I also know that the RHS actually returns an `ArrayList` which is an implementation of `List`. Also, `lines.getClass().getName()` returns `java.util.ArrayList` to be sure.

But surprisingly when I do,

```
ArrayList<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileAddress),
    Charset.defaultCharset());
```

I am getting an error,

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to ArrayList<String>`

How is that possible?

Comment: `readAllLines` is defined to return a `List<String>`, and that's what the calling code must rely on. The fact that it actually returns an `ArrayList<String>` is an implementation detail that can change without impacting callers

Comment: "I also know that the RHS actually returns an ArrayList which is an implementation of List" - how do you know that? By looking at the implementation, or the actual time when executing? The *declaration* of `Files.readAllLines` only says that it returns a `List<String>`

Comment: The compiler compiles your code based on definitions. It does not go snooping inside methods to see what implementations do.  (Luckily.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java compiler doesn't "know" which type will be returned from the method.

`java.util.list` is an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and there is a list with all known list interface implementations.

This is signature for `readAllLines` method
`public static List<String> readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs) throws IOException`
Documentation for [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

The compiler has only information that `readAllLines` method will return `List<String>`, but it has no information which implementation it will be. Because it the compiler cannot compile the code.